# Add column into datagridview taken from database

Tags: c#, sql, workflow-foundation

I'm showing data from database table into datagridview 
each column has a checkbox
for example column named "Tel" has a check box "checkBox_Tel"

```
if (!checkBox_Tel.Checked)
        {
            dg.Columns.Remove("Tel");
        }
```

when the user uncheck one , the column related to this check box is removed from the dgv

but i want to return that column when the user recheck it
how can i do that?

Comment: Did you try anything? Show your work also..

Comment: no i didn't cause i found a method that adds an empty column .. i need the one filled from database

Comment: Put some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is just to hide the column and then restore its visibility then

```
        dg.Columns("Tel").Visible = checkBox_Tel.Checked
```

> Use this property to hide a column from view while keeping the column
>   in the DataGridView. To completely remove a column, use the
>   DataGridViewColumnCollection.Remove method.